# Two Forms on the Same Bootstrap HTML Doc

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get two modal forms to work independently on the same HTML document.
The HTML document is a standard bootstrap template. If I click the submit button in
form 1, nothing happens. However, when I click the submit button in form 2, it
submits the data entered in both forms. Here is the git hub link to the code...

https://github.com/locutustheborg/Bootstrap-Modal-Form/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Comment: We're going to need to see actual code if you want any help with this.

Comment: the code is included by it is not displaying...let me try to edit

Comment: it appears stackoverflow is stripping out the code from the

Comment: posting and won't allow me to post an image. can somebody familiar with bootstrap twitter point me in the right direction on examples or resource that deals with creating more than one model form in a html document..thanks